# Problem when typing quote in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7

When using visual studio - when I type an open quotation character in the code designer nothing happens, it seems like the key command is held back for some reason until I type another quotation character, then both are sent to the screen at once.

Same applies for single quotes, or double quotes.

This is annoying, and I would like normal typing behaviour back, is there any way to fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: This is not only something that can happen in windows 7, i have this on my Windows Vista @ home aswell :(((.

Comment: Even an idea on how to google for this problem would help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Found the answer: changing the default input language for the keyboard to "English (United States) – US" solves the problem.

Source: http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2010/01/15/windows-7-quotes-problem/

Comment: The problem occurs with all keyoards set to "International" because keys like " are used to modify the next stroke to produce chars like ë .

Answer (score 8):

Check your keyboard layout setting on the language bar while Visual Studio has focus and make sure it's what you expect it to be. It sounds like the layout changed to one that supports [dead keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Dead_key).

If you have multiple layouts installed, try setting the change sequence to a specific key instead of just Alt+Shift or Ctrl+Shift (i.e. Alt+Shift+Num). This will cut down on accidental layout changes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code on the Macintosh does not recognize Smart Quotes. If text with quotes is pasted from a program that makes use of the system setting to use smart quotes and dashes, it will lead to the failure. The solution is to disable "Use smart quotes and dashes" in the System Settings (i.e. Click on the Apple icon > "System Settings..." > Keyboard > "Edit..." button in the Text Input section), then reopen your text in the previous Macintosh compatible program you used, re-copy it, and re-paste it into Visual Studio Code.

Comment: asker is/was on windows 7